# OrientationEventListener vs Rotation Vector Sensor to get "orientation"

Tags: android, android-sensors

The first of all my apologies, if I am using wrong terms. I have done some digging and therefore I am a bit confused. I will correct the question if there are wrong terms..

Which one I should prefer ([OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) or [Rotation Vector Sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate)) if I need to get just device "orientation"? And if I have understood the terms correctly then in this case I mean the Yaw by orientation.

As a background then I have an app that is locked to e.g. portrait mode, but I would still like to display Views based on device position. In this case I am not interested about position if the device is flat e.g. lying on table on its back.

I am wondering this, because I can achieve my goal with both of them.