# OrientationEventListener and onOrientationChanged not working correctly

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am trying to detect if an orientation change has happened to the phone using `OrientationEventListener`, but the code does not work as expected. Here are part of my code relevant to this question:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   OrientationEventListener myOrientationEventListener;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ...
      myOrientationEventListener
        = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){
          @Override
          public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
             DO SOMETHING;
          }
      };
      if (myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
         myOrientationEventListener.enable();
      }
```

If I put a breakpoint in debug mode at line `DO SOMETHING` and without moving the phone look at the value of `arg0`, I see it changes to 8 and then 9 and then 8, etc. each time I enter the `onOrientationChanged` function.

My question is: **why it enters the onOrientationChanged function, although the phone is placed on a desk and not moving?**. And the second question is why the value of `arg0` is changing between 8, and 9?

By the way **I have forced my main layout to be portrait** using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Is there anything in the code that I am missing or is not correct? 
Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: why don't you using onConfigurationChanged ?

Comment: You can try like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566633/how-to-use-onconfigurationchanged-and-newconfig-orientation-configuration-o

Comment: @JaiminModi Would that work even though I have forced the layout to `portrait`?

Comment: @JaiminModi do you mean I used `onConfigurationChanged ` instead of `onOrientationChanged`?

Comment: ya bro, i am saying that if you are checking that the app is in landscape or portrait then use onConfigurationChanged().

Comment: Will that work despite the fact that **I have locked the layout to portrait**?

Comment: no it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I do not have enough reputation to add this as a comment:

I have a smilar situation. I have an App that is fixed to portrait mode and I am using OrientationEventListener&&onOrientationChanged to monitor device rotation. In other words my setup is excatly same as TJ1.

What I have observed with my testing then above code is working fine on some devices, but then I have a device (Nokia6, api27) where the code is not working. The "onOrientationChanged"-fn is not called at all.

(As a bit offtopic, then I have asked a question that is related to this topic: 
[OrientationEventListener vs Rotation Vector Sensor to get “orientation”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671273/orientationeventlistener-vs-rotation-vector-sensor-to-get-orientation)
)

Comment: are you saying this could be device dependent?

Comment: My set is way too small to make any definite conclusions. In my case I happen to have four different devices (all >api22) and above are my observations. 

Here I would be curious about the documented behavior. So, if I have an app that is fixed to Portrait mode at app Manifest then would the OrientationEventListener work?